# Validation in C# Records - How to prevent illegal state with the "with" keyword?

Tags: c#, record, with-statement

I have a C# record like so:

```
public record CodeWithContext
{
    public string Description { get; init; }
    public string Value { get; init; }
    public string Code { get; init; }
    public CodeWithContext(string desc, string val, string code)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(desc) &&
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) && 
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("text");
        }
        Description = desc;
        Value = val;
        Code = code;
    }
}
```

An ArgumentException is thrown when all properties are set to an empty string.

However, I've noticed that when I create a new object using the with keyword, it bypasses the constructor and I can create an object in what should be an illegal state:

```
var code = new CodeWithContext("description", "value", "code");
var cut = code with { Code = "", Value = "", Description = "" };
```

In this case, `cut` is a `CodeWithContext` in an illegal state and no error is thrown.

I would like the validation logic to apply regardless of whether the object is created using the constructor or copied using the `with` keyword. How can I achieve this?

---

WARNING: I was a little hasty in accepting the answer below, it DOES NOT allow for copying from a legal state to another legal state if there exists an illegal state in between:

```
    var code = new CodeWithContext("description", "value", "code");
    var firstCopy = code with { Code = "code", Value = "", Description = "" };
    var secondCopy= firstCopy with { Code = "", Value = "val", Description = "" };
```

Here, the initialisation of `secondCopy` will fail as when the `Validate()` method is called on the `Code` property setter, the state of the `CodeWithContext` is `{"","",""}`

---

What I ended up doing was disallowing the use of the `with` keyword for the record by using the default setter:

```
public record CodeWithContext_Simple
{
    public string Description { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
    public string Code { get; }
    public CodeWithContext_Simple(string desc, string val, string code)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(desc) &&
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) &&
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("text");
        }
        Description = desc;
        Value = val;
        Code = code;
    }
}
```

Here, if attempting to copy the record using the `with` keyword, a `CS0200` - `"property or indexer 'propertyname' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"` is observed.